# Custom function in Lambda layer fails, cannot convert tensor to numpy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

So I am trying to implement a custom function using Lambda layers in Keras (Tensorflow backend).

I want to convert the input Tensor into numpy array to perform my function. However, I cannot run tensor.eval() as it throws an error :

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,960,960,1]
```

This is my code:

```
def tensor2np(tensor):
    return tensor.eval(session=K.get_session())

def np2tensor(np):
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(np.reshape((1,480,480,3)))

def calculate_dwt1(tensor):
    np_input = tensor2np(tensor)
    coeff = pywt.wavedec2((np_input[0,:,:,0]), 'db1', level=1)
    return np2tensor(np.dstack((coeff[1][0],coeff[1][1],coeff[1][2])))




def network():

    input = Input(shape=(960,960,1), dtype='float32')
    conv1 = Convolution2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input)
    conv1 = Convolution2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    lambda1 = Lambda(calculate_dwt1)(input)
    me = merge((lambda1, conv2),mode='concat', concat_axis=3)
    ..
    ..
```

Or is there anyway I can get the result of the custom function at runtime and convert to Tensor and feed it into my network?

Basically, I'm trying to implement this model architecture. 
[image: Model Architecture]

Comment: kindly, did you get the answer to your question? coz i am trying to do the same however, still unable to convert tensor to numpy using cutome layer. Please help it you have done that.

Answer (score 2):

As it is, you're asking your network to backpropagate through a) the array-> tensor transformation and b) a blackbox function that operates on arrays. Obviously it's no surprise it's unable to do that. You will need to rewrite your custom function using standard (or custom) TF/K operations, and have it be applied on tensor objects. Then and only then will it be able to propagate gradients backwards and values forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a pure python function as a TensorFlow operation, you can use [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func).

In your case, you need to use a custom python function as a loss function instead of built-in operations. TensorFlow's built-in operations are symbolic and compiled before execution. Then TensorFlow optimizes the given cost function by using its gradients. As your custom loss function's gradient is unknown, TensorFlow cannot optimize your custom loss function.

You have two options. You can either define your custom function in a more symbolic way in order to utilize TF's automatic differentiation, or you need to provide your pure python function's gradient externally like [this](https://gist.github.com/harpone/3453185b41d8d985356cbe5e57d67342).